# Вернуть исходное состояние при false

Tags: php

```
$var = 'ИванИванов';
echo stristr($var, ' ', true);
```

Не выведет ничего, т.к нет пробела. Как выводить переменную `$var`, если пробела не обнаружено?

Comment: Ничего не понятно... Вам нужно выполнять какое-то действие по условию: "если в строке есть пробел" ?

Comment: @Эдуард для строк `Иван Иванов` и `Иван` необходимо в обоих случаях выводить `Иван`

Comment: А для `ИванИванов` ничего не выводить?

Comment: @Эдуард если не найдено пробела, то выводить `ИванИванов`.

Comment: `?? $var` туда добавьте в вашему выводу да и все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *если не найдено пробела, то выводить `ИванИванов`*

```
$var = 'Иван Иванов';

if (strpos($var, ' ') === false) {
    echo $var;
} else {
    echo stristr($var, ' ', true);
}
```

Comment: а в противном случае выводить часть до пробела

Comment: @teran подправил )

Comment: А для чего два раза пробел искать?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, что я не правильно понял вопрос, но в данной ситуации достаточно сокращенной записи тернарного оператора, основываясь на том, что функция `stristr()` возвращает `FALSE`, если искомая подстрока не найдена. Т.е. создание промежуточных переменных избыточно.

```
echo stristr($var, ' ', true) ?: $var;
```

Answer (score -3):

Коротко -

```
 echo (($k = stristr($var, ' ', true)) !== false)?$k:$var;
```

Длинно -

```
 if(($k = stristr($var, ' ', true)) !== false) {
     echo $k;
 } else {
     echo $var;
 }
```

Comment: Я тебе открою великую тайну, все функции возвращают `false` в случае ошибки, но лишь некоторые из них `могут возвращать как логическое значение false, так и значение не типа boolean`.